# To find the disparity map for an stereo image pair

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, image-processing

Please look into the following error and give me a solution. The code talks about stereo matching.

Results: display the disparity map

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
imgL=cv2.imread('C:\Users\harsha\Desktop\stereo  vision\images_stereo_1\cam2_object3.jpg')
imgR=cv2.imread('C:\Users\harsha\Desktop\stereo  vision\images_stereo_1\cam3_object3.jpg')
stereo = cv2.StereoBM()
disp=stereo.compute(imgL,imgR,disptype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
CV2.imshow(window_name,disparity/255)

Error:
raceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\stereo.py", line 21, in <module>
    disp=stereo.compute(imgL,imgR,disptype=cv2.CV_8UC1)

error: ..\..\..\..\opencv\modules\calib3d\src\stereobm.cpp:1089: error: (-215) disptype == CV_16S || disptype == CV_32F in function cv::StereoBM::operator ()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you had only looked at your error, you would have seen that you are not passing a valid `disptype`.

Change

```
disp=stereo.compute(imgL,imgR,disptype=cv2.CV_8UC1)
```

to

```
disp=stereo.compute(imgL,imgR,disptype=cv2.CV_32F)
```